# Ruby method with argument hash with default values: how to DRY?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have an `initialize` method that accepts a hash to set some instance variables. This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
class Ad
  DEFAULT_PAGE = 'index'.freeze

  DEFAULT_CHANNEL = 'general'.freeze

  DEFAULT_AREA = 'general'.freeze

  attr_accessor :page, :area, :channel

  def initialize args={}
    @page = args[:page] || DEFAULT_PAGE
    @area = args[:area] || DEFAULT_AREA
    @channel = args[:channel] || DEFAULT_CHANNEL
  end

  # ...
end
```

I saw a tip to allow dynamic setting of instance variables, but I'm not sure how to also include the default values...

```
  def initialize args={}
    args.each do |attr,val|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", val) unless val.nil?
    end
  end
```

Can I refer to a constant dynamically? Or any better ways of doing this sort of thing are welcome!

... I also realize that `attr_accessor` variables can be set individually. But I just want to do it like this. :)

Comment: What is `v` in the third line of the definition of `initialize`?

Comment: Meant to put `val`... thanks for the catch

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's a nice clean way to use an options hash with defaults values as a parameter in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977535/whats-a-nice-clean-way-to-use-an-options-hash-with-defaults-values-as-a-paramete). But don't feel bad - it was an effort to find the duplicate!

Comment: Thanks, I did try to find a duplicate but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This one also only creates the instance variables if they are in your `defaults` hash, so that you don't accidentally create/overwrite other instance variables.

I'm assuming you meant to say `unless val.nil?`:

```
def initialize(args={})
  defaults = {
    :page    => DEFAULT_PAGE,
    :area    => DEFAULT_AREA,
    :channel => DEFAULT_CHANNEL
  }.merge(args).each do |attr, val|
    instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", val) if defaults.has_key?(attr) && (not val.nil?)
  end if args
end
```

Comment: Yep, I did mean to put `unless val.nil?`... thanks, I also didn't want to expose any other instance variables from being set. Thanks!

Comment: @Jorge: if `defaults` contain an boolean assignment with `false` value, instance variable isn't created; i think that last part of your code should read: `...if defaults.has_key?(attr) && (not val.nil?)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  def initialize args={}
    defaults = {
      :page    => DEFAULT_AREA, 
      :area    => DEFAULT_AREA, 
      :channel => DEFAULT_CHANNEL
    }
    args.reverse_merge(defaults).each do |attr,val|
      instance_variable_set("@#{attr}", val) unless val.nil?
    end
  end
```

Comment: IIRC `reverse_merge` is implemented in ActiveSupport, hence, it will not be available in vanilla Ruby without importing ActiveSupport.

Comment: `v.nil?` should be `val.nil?`